# NuxtJS - Google Auth: ExpiredAuthSessionError: Both token and refresh token have expired. Your request was aborted

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

Im using nuxtjs for a while. Before my last update all auth feature run smoothly.
But after I update the `nuxt.config.js` move axios plugin from `plugins` array to `auth` config object the error occurred. I need to put axios in auth config object because I need to access `$auth` from axios plugin.

#### Version

- "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1607693598.34d83ea"
- "nuxt": "^2.15.2"

#### Nuxt configuration

##### [Mode](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode):

- Universal

#### Nuxt configuration

```
  auth: {
    plugins: [{ src: "~/plugins/axios.js", ssr: true }], // <-- I put this, move from plugins array
    strategies: {
      local: {
        token: {
          property: "data.token",
          required: true,
          type: "",
          maxAge: 18000,
        },
        user: {
          property: "data",
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: "/api/main", method: "post" },
          logout: { url: "/api/profiles/logout", method: "get" },
          user: { url: "/api/profile", method: "get" },
        },
      },
      google: {
        responseType: "code",
        clientId:"<google client ID>",
        codeChallengeMethod: "",
        grantType: "authorization_code",
        redirectUri: `${baseUrl}/verify-auth`,
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: "/login",
      logout: "/login",
      callback: "/login",
      home: "/",
    },
  },
```

### Reproduction

> ExpiredAuthSessionError: Both token and refresh token have expired. Your request was aborted.
> at a5d2e4e.js:1:4374

##### Steps to reproduce

After selecting a google account, then redirected to /verify-auth, then the error occurred. After /verify-auth it should go in.

Answer (score 0):

Update google auth config like this:

```js
google: {
        responseType: "code",
        clientId:"<google client ID>",
        codeChallengeMethod: "",
        grantType: "authorization_code",
        redirectUri: `${baseUrl}/verify-auth`,

token: {
          property: "data.token", // <-- based on your API response (endpints.login)
          required: true,
          type: "",
          maxAge: 18000,
        },
        user: {
          property: "data",
          autoFetch: true,
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: "{your google auth API}", method: "post" }, // <-- should return response with token on it
          logout: { url: "/api/profiles/logout", method: "get" },
          user: { url: "/api/profile", method: "get" },
        },
      }
```

Comment: It's should depend on how you implement the auth. Also recommended to upgrade the `@nuxtjs/auth-next` to the newest version.